# Conditional values in MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a question about MySQL triggers—say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT(6),
    value_1 INT(6),
    value_2 INT(6),
    values_were_set BOOL
)
```

Now, every time I insert a value into this table I want to have a trigger check if `value_1` and `value_2` have been set. And if they are, it should set `values_were_set` to true.

`NULL` values are allowed.

How would I go about this? In the real table there are about ten columns that I want to check for, so I would fancy not to have to use a bunch of `IF` statements.

Maybe it's better to do it in the app?

Comment: If you want to do it with a trigger, its a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. I don't really see why tho, you can always determine the value of the 'were_set' field during the SELECT, by looking for NULLs

Comment: Thanks pala_ for your input. Yes, I know this is possible to check for in the app layer, and that's how it's working right now. I just wanted to see if it was possible to do it directly in the DB instead, that would make it easier when we start working with different apps to the same DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then trigger it is:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER value_check BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.value_1 IS NOT NULL AND NEW.value_2 IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET NEW.values_were_set = 1;
  ELSE
    SET NEW.values_were_set = 0;
  END IF;
END;
$$
```

Unfortunately yes, I think you would need a nasty if/else section in the trigger if you want to check multiple combinations of fields